# How to change decimal separator from dot to coma in Pandas when column have NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to open my ready files in Excel, it changes my decimals number to data. I try to change dot to coma in decimals numbers, and it work. I used this code to change it:

```py
def convert_df(df):
    return df.to_csv(sep=';',decimal=',').encode('utf-8')
```

Problem is that I have some NaN values in my DataFrame. I changed NaN values to '-' to make it look prettier. This function above does not change dot to coma in columns that have this '-' value.

I try this code too:

```py
DF['Age'].replace('.',',',inplace=True)
```

But this solutions work in the same way as this first one.

Anyone has some solutions for this problem?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [1.1, 1.2, 1.3],
        "col2": [1.1, pd.NA, 1.3],
    }
)

print(df)  # Toy dataframe
   col1  col2
0   1.1   1.1
1   1.2  <NA>
2   1.3   1.3
```

```py
df.fillna("-").applymap(lambda x: str(x).replace(".", ",")).to_csv(
    path_or_buf="df.csv", sep=";", index=False
)
```

When you open `df.csv` in Excel:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this work just fine. Problem solved.